# Why my code in java does not output the message "you have broken the rule" even if I inputed the number out of the given range?

Tags: java

I am using the if else statement to output the message Exelent or you have broken the rule based on the user input. However, why my code always output the Excelent! although I have written the number out of the given range?

The code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class numberOfChoice{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int choosenNumber;
            Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Write your number in between 1 and 100");
            choosenNumber=input.nextInt();
            if (choosenNumber>0 && choosenNumber<100) {
                System.out.println("Excelent!");
            } else{
                System.out.println("You have broken the rule");
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to add the output as a picture but I could not upload it.

Comment: Have you tried to output "choosenNumber" before the if statement to see what it does?

Comment: You are actually accepting 1 to 99 as a valid number.

Comment: Can you please give an example of which numbers you tested your code with?

Comment: I have tested with 111 and -1 but the message excelent has been provided

Comment: You should include your output *as text*. Why would you want to do this as a picture?

Comment: *"I would like to add the output as a picture but I could not upload it."* - That's a GOOD thing.  Images of text output are troublesome for a lot of reasons.  We want you to *copy and paste* the output as text, not link to an image.  Also, show us exactly what you are doing to compile and run the program.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I'm unable to replicate this problem. When I copy paste this code and run it, it runs as expected. Try running it in another compiler and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work, but I would suggest running the code in another IDE (you can find a few online, try this one: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler, it's pretty good).

Maybe double-check to see if you are running the wrong program (although very unlikely), and make sure what you input is correct. Also check to see if the code is the same - especially in the if-else statement, make sure it's `&&` (and) and not `||` (or).